# AWS RDS (MySQL) does not output all column content onto Excel via VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, amazon-rds

I have a AWS RDS instance using MySQL. The login has full admin right.

I am trying to perform a `SELECT * FROM table` and output all the contents of the table onto an Excel worksheet using VBA. Still kind of new to this so I am starting with the basics.

I am using the chunk of code below:

```
Sub test()
Dim Server_Name As String, DB_Name As String, User_ID As String, User_Pass As String
Dim Rs As Variant, Cn As Variant
Dim sqlStr As String
Dim includeField As Boolean
Dim tgtCell As Range
Dim col As Long


Server_Name = "arachnophobia.blabla.rds.amazonaws.com"
DB_Name = "Spidey"
User_ID = "Peter"
User_Pass = "Parker"

sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM crime"

Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};" & _
                ";Server=" & Server_Name & _
                ";Database=" & DB_Name & _
                ";Uid=" & User_ID & _
                ";Pwd=" & User_Pass

Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set Rs = Cn.Execute(sqlStr)

Set tgtCell = Sheets("Main").Range("A1")
includeField = True
If includeField Then
    tgtCell.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Rs
    For col = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheets(tgtCell.Parent.Name).Cells(1, col + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(col).Name
    Next
Else
    tgtCell.CopyFromRecordset Rs
End If

End Sub
```

The `crime` table consists of 4 column:

```
|S/N (PK) |DateID    |CrimeID    |Reason    |
|1        |01/02/19  |32155      |Fun       |
|2        |03/02/19  |32255      |Bored     |
|3        |06/02/19  |32555      |Meh       |
|4        |07/02/19  |32755      |Duh       |
|5        |09/02/19  |32855      |Null      |
```

I executed the code above and the output on the Excel sheet is:

```
|S/N (PK) |DateID    |CrimeID    |Reason    |
|1        |          |           |          |
|2        |          |           |          |
|3        |          |           |          |
|4        |          |           |          |
|5        |          |           |          |
```

Basically, I am only getting the Field names and the Primary Key values but not anything else.

I tried running the same code on my local server and it works just fine.

Is there anything I did not take into consideration in the code that causes all the missing column information?

**Update:**

I have done more testing. `tgtCell.CopyFromRecordset Rs` results in the output above. However, if I try looping through the recordset using this:

```
xlrow = 1
Do While Not Rs.EOF
    xlcol = 1
    For col = 1 To Rs.Fields.Count
        tgtCell.Offset(xlrow, xlcol - 1).Value = Rs(col - 1).Value
        xlcol = xlcol + 1
    Next
    Rs.movenext
    xlrow = xlrow + 1
Loop
```

I will end up with my desired output. I don't quite understand why this is so? Was I missing some kind of library reference?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you remove the following code?

```
For col = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Sheets(tgtCell.Parent.Name).Cells(1, col + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(col).Name
Next
```

To me, your line `tgtCell.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Rs` should just copy the data straight in so I'm wondering if your subsequent code is overwriting/clearing the data.

Comment: thanks for the input. I have removed the suggested chunk of code and it still does not work :(

Comment: I have done more testing and have updated in the question :)